# Doubt about definition of complete statistic

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I know a statistic $T$ is complete if for any measurable function $g$, $E(g(T))=0$ implies $g(T)=0$ a.s. But what if I take $g(T)=T-E(T)$?
The expectation of $g(T)$ is 0, but not necessarily also $g$ is. Following this, the sample mean in a normal model, for example, would not be complete.
Where am I getting this wrong?
Thank you

Comment: How do you know what $E[T]$ is?  In your $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ model with $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ unknown, clearly $E[\frac 1n \sum x_i] =\mu$ but you cannot define $g(T)=T-\mu$ as a function of $T$ until you know what $\mu$ is.

Answer (score 2):

The question has essentially already been answered in a comment. A statistic is by definition a function of the data, and the function $g$ in the definition of a complete statistic is a function of the statistic only. It cannot depend on the parameter(s). If $E(T)$ doesn’t depend on the parameter(s) and $T$ isn’t almost surely constant for all parameter values (so that your $g(T)$ isn’t almost surely zero for all parameter values), then $T$ is indeed not complete. But that’s not usually the case. In your example, the sample mean [is a complete statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Sample_mean) for a normal distribution with unknown mean; the expected value depends on the unknown mean and thus your construction doesn’t yield a function of the statistic only.